# jquery hover effect not working in all div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add some text infront of images when we hover. But its working on first div only. When i hover the remaining divs it not working. What should i do if i want to work in all div's?

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5mFLr/)

**Jquery**

```
$("#image").hover(function () {

    $("#imgtext").slideToggle(250, function () {
        $("#showme").slideToggle(250);
    });
}, function () {

    $("#showme").slideToggle(250, function () {
        $("#imgtext").slideToggle(250);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="image">
    <img src="first.jpg" width="260" height="160"/>
    <div id="imgtext"> Description of above image </div>
    <div id="showme"> Show me </div>
</div><br>
<div id="image">
    <img src="first.jpg" width="260" height="160"/>
    <div id="imgtext"> Description of above image </div>
    <div id="showme"> Show me </div>
</div><br>
<div id="image">
    <img src="first.jpg" width="260" height="160"/>
    <div id="imgtext"> Description of above image </div>
    <div id="showme"> Show me </div>
</div><br>
```

**CSS**

```
    #image
    {
        position: relative;
    }
    #imgtext
    {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        width: 260px;
        height: 30px;
    }
    #showme
    {
        width: 260px;
        height: 160px;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        top: 0;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers say ID must be unique, but also you can improve your function to work in the right way try this:

```
$(".image").hover(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.find(".imgtext").slideToggle(250, function () {
      $this.find(".showme").slideToggle(250);
  });
})
```

Check the **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8UNNz/)**

Comment: its working. but effect will appear when i hover the cursor outside of div?? i changed this `.image{position: relative;}` to `.image{position: absolute;}`. but its not look good..

Comment: Yep you are right @user3181207 that's becuase the div is `block`you can trick that with `float` or `display:inline-block` check this http://jsfiddle.net/8UNNz/1/

Answer (score 5):

Change `id="image"` to `class="image"` **ID must be unique**

**HTML**

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="first.jpg" width="260" height="160"/>
    <div class="imgtext"> Description of above image </div>
    <div class="showme"> Show me </div>
</div><br>
<div class="image">
    <img src="first.jpg" width="260" height="160"/>
    <div class="imgtext"> Description of above image </div>
    <div class="showme"> Show me </div>
</div><br>
<div class="image">
    <img src="first.jpg" width="260" height="160"/>
    <div class="imgtext"> Description of above image </div>
    <div class="showme"> Show me </div>
</div><br>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".image").hover(function () {
    $that = $(this);
    $that.find(".imgtext").slideToggle(250, function () {
        $that.find(".showme").slideToggle(250);
    });
}, function () {
    $that = $(this);
    $that.find(".showme").slideToggle(250, function () {
        $that.find(".imgtext").slideToggle(250);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.image{
position: relative;
}
.imgtext{
    position: absolute;bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    width: 260px;height: 30px;
}
.showme{
    width: 260px;height: 160px;display: none;
    position: absolute;background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    top: 0;color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5mFLr/2/)

If you want to create an `accordian` then you can try [jquery-ui-autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) or [css-trick-autocomplete](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/)

Answer (score 1):

```
id should be unique in a `html` code. use `class` instead of `id` and now 

$(".image").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".imgText").slideToggle(250, function () {
        $(this).find(".showme").slideToggle(250);
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".showme").slideToggle(250, function () {
        $(this).find(".imgText").slideToggle(250);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use ID as selector, it just allow you to chose the first match on the page, as an ID it's made to be unique, just change the ID to class and it will work fine, you gonna need to change the matching jquery too.

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2QSzL/
It needs some fixes but's the main idea it's there.

```
$(this).find
```

As you can see in the code, these was changed to match the needs from the new elements.